# In BigQuery, how to filter on json for rows where sum of some subelements is positive?

Tags: google-bigquery

Following up on [How to get count of matches in field of table for list of phrases from another table in bigquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55051157/how-to-get-count-of-matches-in-field-of-table-for-list-of-phrases-from-another-t/55051345#55051345)
Where you end up with something like:

```
Row str                     all_matches  
1   foo1 foo foo40          [{"key":"foo","matches":2},{"key":"test","matches":0}]   
2   test1 test test2 test   [{"key":"foo","matches":0},{"key":"test","matches":2}]
```

How could you further filter on those rows for which sum(matches over all keys) > 0 with StandardSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep it simple - just add below line to the end of referenced query

```
HAVING SUM(ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(str, CONCAT(key, r'[^\s]')))) > 0
```

So, the final query (BigQuery Standard SQL) will be

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'foo1 foo foo40' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'test1 test test2 test' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc xyz'
), `project.dataset.keywords` AS (
  SELECT 'foo' key UNION ALL
  SELECT 'test'
)
SELECT str, 
  TO_JSON_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(key, ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(str, CONCAT(key, r'[^\s]'))) AS matches))) all_matches
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.keywords`
GROUP BY str
HAVING SUM(ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(str, CONCAT(key, r'[^\s]')))) > 0
```

with result

```
Row str                     all_matches  
1   foo1 foo foo40          [{"key":"foo","matches":2},{"key":"test","matches":0}]   
2   test1 test test2 test   [{"key":"foo","matches":0},{"key":"test","matches":2}]
```

Note: I added one more row into dummy data and it is filtered out from output because there is no matches at all in that row

Comment: what if you wanted to not spit out keys that have zero matches?

Comment: you should post your new questions with all related details. meantime  - PLEASE - try first by yourself - otherwise it looks like you are outsourcing your job/homework. we are happy to help - but show your attempts first :o)

Comment: Hint: it is extremely easy!

Comment: yeah sorry - I was just musing too quickly - I'm sure there are lots of ways to do it - I played with a javascript UDF and JSON.parse/stringify+array filter, just because I just learned you can even have a javascript UDF

Comment: as I mentioned - it is very easy  - so no UDF to be involved :o) - just try - and if still an issue  - post new question